# Angular 5 - Using HTTP Interceptors as mock HTTP requests in Jasmine / Karma tests

Tags: angular, mocking, httprequest, karma-jasmine, angular-http-interceptors

In use case tests written using Jasmine and Karma for components written using Angular, can you use HTTP interceptors as mock HTTP requests and responses? If yes, what's one example of using interceptors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to use HTTPInterceptors, if you only want to use mocked HTTP requests, you can simply use mocked Services. Lets say you have a simple data.service.ts like this:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()
export class DataService {

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {

    }

    getData(): Observable<Data[]> {
      return this.http.get<Data[]>(url);
    }
}
```

You can mock your in a file called mockData.service.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()
export class MockDataService {
// Your data goes either here or import it via an external file
data: Data[] = [
...
];
constructor() {

}

// Use the same name for the method here
getData(): Observable<Data[]> {
  return Obersvable.of(this.data);
}
```

In your test file component.spec.ts you simply use the mocked dataservice like this inside of `TestBed.configureTestingModule`:

```
providers: [
            {
                provide: DataService,
                useClass: MockDataService
            }
]
```

Just define all the http methods that get used in the component you're testing and provide the according data.

Hope this helps!

Comment: My assignment currently does not involve using a service, but basically I want to simulate a 500 Internal Server Error response to some actual HTTP requests I'm making. Not sure how this comes into play.

Comment: Ah sorry I misunderstood you then. Have you already checked the [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/http#intercepting-requests-and-responses) for Http Interceptors? What have you tried so far?

Comment: I actually did something else. From posting a [new StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52302537/angular-5-karma-jasmine-testing-using-a-mock-backend-to-mock-error-respons/52302735#52302735), I used HttpClient instead. 

I didn't read the documentation on Http interceptors, but I'm leaving this question open for other people to give some votes.

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented is as follows
1. Define one variable in service which indicates mock response like isMockResponse = true.
2. I created one config file which has a mapping of URL vs response JSON file.
like this

```
{ POST : { "/login": { responseFile: loginResponse.json}}}
```

I kept responseFile under asset folder and making sure that the response file folder should be excluded on a production build. (you can define it in angular.json file)
3. create loginResponse.json file inside assets/offline/response/loginResponse.json location
4. in the interceptor, I am checking the flag isMockResponse and if it's true then redirect request to get a file from the assets folder instead of going to the server.

```
 let rspFile = "/assets/offline/response/" + extn + ".json";
  Utility.log("rspFile " + rspFile);
  const dupReq = request.clone({ url: rspFile, method: "get" });
  return next.handle(dupReq);
```

Where extn is the "loginResponse" which I am getting from configuration file. This way, you don't need to customise code.In case of isMockresponse= false you simply forward request to server like this

```
return next.handle(request);
```