# Angular 5 (Karma / Jasmine Testing) - Using a mock backend to mock error responses for error messages

Tags: angular, unit-testing, mocking, backend, http-error

I don't quite understand how the MockBackend feature works as [described over here](https://angular.io/api/http/testing/MockBackend). I am completely new to Angular.

I want to program some test cases to make sure that when a server error occurs in the backend, the Angular components I have do display error messages on the frontend. That requires having HTTP requests that return errors on purpose. I am running into trouble with the jasmine-ajax and the nock packages, but someone told me about programming an instance

Even if you have an actual backend already implemented, can you still create a mock backend to test appearance of form messages which do require HTTP requests first before they are displayed?

One example is when the user is asked to fill out a sales form, and upon sending it over, the server encounters an error and sends a 500 Internal Server Error response back, which the frontend then displays a server error message.

I don't quite understand mock backends in Angular. My worry is that by having a mock backend, it will cause *all* the requests I'm making in the controllers of the components, as well as the requests made in the test cases, be issued to the *mock backend instead of the actual backend*, thereby introducing false-positive fails in my test suite.

If I program my test suite to use the MockBackend class from '@angular/http/testing', **will this cause my HTTP requests on all the Angular components to be issued to that mock backend server instead of the actual server?**

EDIT: This is a [case of what I'm referring to](https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/unit-testing/http-and-jsonp/#_using_the_code_mockbackend_code_to_simulate_a_response). By using MockBackend, some of the tests that require sending HTTP requests to the actual server **will not be sent.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct me if I'm wrong, judging by your description I assume you're using `http` module. You could consider upgrading to the [`httpClient`](https://angular.io/guide/http) module, for which testing against server errors is pretty straightforward: https://angular.io/guide/http#testing-for-errors

By the way unit tests should be self contained. You should mock all the dependencies (probably providers for your testing module) and not send any requests to the actual server. Both information and status codes can be mocked using [http testing module](https://angular.io/guide/http#testing-http-requests).

Comment: There's sort of a disagreement here: I need to write test cases where I do have valid information and the server does return "OK" responses as well. How would I do that?

Otherwise, in the controllers of the components, I am using HttpClient and calling the respective methods for the kinds of requests I want to make.

Comment: Okay, let me try that. I'll get back soon.

Comment: What I don't understand is why even in the development phase and not at the prototype phase, these tests should not send actual HTTP requests to the server. This is a bit of a limitation in some cases, although I can't exactly describe what.

Comment: It might be a limitation, it is a liability though when you include an unnecessary external dependency to your unit tests. Imagine a scenario when your server is not available and you're trying to push your changes to the remote repository where your tests are hooked to a script checking if everything passes and nicely shines green. No server means failing tests. Should they fail in this case? Absolutely not.

Answer (score 1):

I consider mocking httpclient to be a code smell. I prefer creating my own api classes that wrap http or httpClient. Then in your unit tests you can use a jasmin spy to return data you need for your tests.

see this example https://angular.io/guide/http

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class ConfigService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
}

configUrl = 'assets/config.json';

getConfig() {
  return this.http.get(this.configUrl);
}
```

then in your tests (pseudo code, don't remember the syntax):

```
spyOn(configService, 'getConfig').and.returnValues({data:123});
```

Comment: How is mocking HttpClient a code smell? That doesn't make sense. :(

Comment: Because you don't want your code to be tightly coupled to anything external (databases, apis, etc) as it makes unit testing harder. The original poster talked about a special mocking framework to replicate httpClient. This is really overkill and unnecessary and can be avoided by decoupling your code.

Comment: what is the server responding with when it has an error? do you have an error handling function? are you able to pass that error data to the error function and then check the UI changes as required?

Comment: Well, I can't explain what the actual code is, but a similar example I can give is maybe a form to fill out someone's contact info including phone number and so on. When the server encounters an error, it sets a Boolean flag that triggers a message in the template to be displayed, evaluated by an *ngIf; simply one sentence in a DIV that has a Bootstrap CSS alert class. 

This is what I'm essentially mocking: either a successful response or an error response _without making an HTTP request_ to the actual server itself. All I'm testing is the appearance of alert messages based on user input.